# Automated testing in Android Automotive

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-auto, android-automotive

What are the best frameworks or tools for automated testing in Android Automotive?

I read about [Spectatio](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/tools/spectatio) but I couldn't find code examples or anything other than what's mentioned on the Android page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into [CATBox](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/tools/catbox?hl=en) documentation, it's based on Spectatio framework. You can build and run catbox from AOSP by following Build [CATBox](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/tools/catbox?hl=en#build-catbox) documentation.

BTW, Are you looking for testing framework for your unbundled applications? (which means app will be installed to Android Automotive through Play or else) or, your Android Automotive builds with preinstalled apps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I want to test a single app that won't be on Play Store but could be a part of an OEM's installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

For automotive you can just use

1. CATbox
2. Spectatio - built on top of `UIAutomator`